# Custom Plugin Field Using Wrong Template Path

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I'm trying to build a simple dropdown field with a pre-populated set of options, so I figured I'd just import most of the methods from Craft's native Dropdown field. The plugin name is `siteutilities` and the field name is `Regionselect`:

```
namespace kgrote\siteutilities\fields;

use kgrote\siteutilities\SiteUtilities;

use Craft;
use craft\base\ElementInterface;
use craft\fields\BaseOptionsField;
```

This pulls in the code from `craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/BaseOptionsField.php`.

So now I want to render a custom settings template for my plugin:

```
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate(
        '_components/fields/Regionselect_settings',
        [
            'field' => $this,
        ]
    );
}
```

But I get a Twig error:

> Unable to find the template
>   “_components/fields/Regionselect_settings”.

My plugin file structure looks like this:

```
kgrote
|-siteutilities
  |-src
    |-fields
    |  |-Regionselect.php
    |-templates
    |  |-_components
    |    |-fields
    |      |-Regionselect_settings.html
    |-SiteUtilities.php
```

Comment: It searches for your template as well. Are you sure it's the correct path? Do you use a custom module instead of a plugin eventually?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I think so, I've updated the question with my plugin's file structure. And no I don't use a custom module, just a plugin.

Comment: Why a php file? You can only render twig and html files. All others won't be parsed/proceed by Twig

Comment: @RobinSchambach Sorry that was a typo, it's a HTML file, I've updated the question.

Comment: You need to include your plugin handle at the first position `plugin-handle/_components/fields/Regionselect_settings`

Comment: @RobinSchambach Ah ha! That did it! If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Sorry for being so slow. I somehow overview that mistake at the first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render a template within your custom plugin you need to include your plugin handle in front of your template path. For example

```
plugin-handle/_components/fields/Regionselect_settings
```